# How do I derive the variance of the binomial distribution with differentiation of the generating function?

Tags: binomial-distribution, variance

I can't seem to detect where I'm going wrong so maybe I've made a fundamental flaw in my derivation.

First I start with
$$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

Then I differentiate with respect to x and multiply by x to get,

$$xn(x+y)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k}x^k y^{n-k}$$

At this point I can simply plug in $x=p$ and $y=1-p$ to get the mean, $pn$ as usual.

I differentiate with respect to x again and then multiply by x, yielding,

$$x \frac{d}{dx} \left( xn(x+y)^{n-1} \right) = \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$
$$x(n(x+y)^{n-1} + x n(n-1)(x+y)^{n-2}) = \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$
$$xn(x+y)^{n-1} + x^2 n(n-1)(x+y)^{n-2} = \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

This formula should be true with x and y as independent variables. It's simply the relation between the right hand side to the mildly nicer left hand side.

Now plugging in $x=p$ and $y=1-p$ out comes what should be the variance,

$$pn(p+1-p)^{n-1} + p^2 n(n-1)(p+1-p)^{n-2} = \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
Which simplifies considerably to

$$pn+p^2 n^2-p^2n$$

However I know the variance of the binomial distribution is

$$pn -p^2n$$

So how did I accidentally acquire this extra $p^2n^2$ term, I can't seem to find the mistake in my derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum
$$\sum k^2\binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
is not $V(X)$ but $E(X^2)$. The variance is
$$V(X) = E(X^2)- E(X)^2$$

Comment: Ah duh, I need to go to sleep obviously. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an $(E(X))^2$ term in your formula.  You have only found the expected value of $E(X^2)$ but the variance is defined as $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. So it should be $pn+p^2n^2-p^2n-(np)^2=pn-p^2n$